# Diagnostic display apear on open the add-in

Tags: c#, excel, excel-dna

We have the add-in to excel written in C#. We are using Excel-DNA also. Lately we got this window on startup of Add-in
[image]

Any idea what is this window and how we can turn of it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer from @Govert is helpful, but if you don't want to correct error and warnings in this window and not to see it you need to paste this part of code in your app.config file:

```
<!--Switch off the diagnostic -->
<system.diagnostics>
   <sources>
      <source name="ExcelDna.Integration" switchValue="Off"></source>
   </sources>
</system.diagnostics>
```

Comment: You might also be interested in redirecting messages to a different logger and have more control of how they're interpreted (error, warning, info, etc.). See [ExcelDna.Diagnostics.Serilog](https://github.com/augustoproiete/exceldna-diagnostics-serilog)

Answer (score 4):

By default, Excel-DNA will try to register all `public static` methods in public types in the assemblies listed as `<ExternalLibrary ...>` in the .dna file.

For your add-in, there seems to be more than one such function called 'Modulus' that Excel-DNA is trying to register. The error arises from this duplication (one registration is being overwritten by another).

You have a few ways around this:

- Make sure you only have one 'Modulus' function being registered, either by making one of the methods not public, or enabling 'ExplictExports=true' in your .dna file and marking all functions with `ExcelFunction` attributes.
- Make sure you don't have additional libraries set up as `<ExternalLibrary>` in the .dna file - extra assemblies that you want to pack into a single-file .xll should be added as `<Reference>` tags - these are not examined for functions and registered with Excel.
- You can control how the logging works, and thus prevent the error window from showing, by customising the logging settings in the .xll.config file - see https://github.com/Excel-DNA/ExcelDna/wiki/Diagnostic-Logging.